# Does systemd-timesyncd still check for the presence of other ntp daemons?

Tags: systemd, ntp, systemd-timesyncd

In `buster`, the following command could be used to list the configuration of `systemd-timesyncd`:

```bash
$ systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd
```

Note the reference at the end of the `cat` listing to a `[Unit]`, with location `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/disable-with-time-daemon.conf`, and its (apparent) instructions ***not*** to run `systemd-timesyncd` if another ntp-like daemon is installed:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/disable-with-time-daemon.conf
[Unit]
# don't run timesyncd if we have another NTP daemon installed
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/ntpd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/openntpd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/chronyd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService
```

At ***some point*** after the release of `buster` (concurrent w/ release of `bullseye`??), the above scheme was altered; in my current `bullseye` systems the file `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/disable-with-time-daemon.conf` no longer exists. Further, the command `systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd` no longer contains any references to restricting or inhibiting startup of `systemd-timesyncd`. I *seem to recall* reading somewhere that `systemd-timesyncd` retained a mechanism for inhibiting its startup if it found other timekeeping daemons installed, but I've been unable to confirm that.

Does anyone recall the history of this change?  More importantly, does `systemd-timesyncd` still inhibit its startup if it finds another timekeeping daemon installed? Where/how is this done?

Comment: See this [answer on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/758103/286615)